# Running Django Rest Framework inside Apache

Tags: python, apache, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a web server running Apache, and I need to implement a RESTful API on the same domain, and I'd like to use Django Restful Framework to serve the REST calls.

For example: going to http://myawesomedomain.com/ in a browser serves a good old fashioned web page delivered by Apache, but I need requests to http://myawesomedomain.com/api/customers/... to be handled by my Django Restful application.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Is there an apache mod I need to activate to get it to serve Python? Do I have to redirect those requests to another service on the server?

Not looking for a comprehensive tutorial. I just don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and found the answer myself.

You use mod_wsgi.

Here is a perfect tutorial to get started: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/